# Xcode 7 Swift Framework Cannot import module being compiled

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

My framework WebCoreDataStaticLibrary was working fine with ios 8.3 in Xcode 6.3. After I updated to ios 9 and Xcode 7 I am not able to compile my framework. This framework contain both swift and Objective C classes.

I have converted to To Latest Swift Syntax via Xcode

In any swift classes where I have imported WebCoreDataStaticLibrary its coming Cannot import module being compiled.

```
import WebCoreDataStaticLibrary Cannot import module being compiled
```

As a result I am not able to build the framework As a result getting this fatal error.

```
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /*/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3WebCoreDataStaticLibrary-ctaegtiwmwhrsdeggeswpkjvucua/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3WebCoreDataStaticLibrary.framework/A3WebCoreDataStaticLibrary (No such file or directory) Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

[image]

Project Settings

[image]

Comment: is it a problem with Swift 2.0? did you migrate your your code to swift 2.0?

Comment: The Framework is complied in Xcode 6.3 . In XCode 7 inittialy it was showing some syntax error for swift 2.0 along with avobe errors.  After that I  converted  To Latest Swift Syntax via Xcode.

Comment: Build the dependent libraries in with Xcode 7 and build this library.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you the problem. It can't find `A3WebCoreDataStaticLibrary.framework/A3WebCoreDataStaticLibrary`.

I even know why. There is no directory on your file system named `/*/`.

Something in your project settings is set wrong. My guess is your Framework Search Paths is wrong, or the Link Binary With Libraries section is wrong. Without knowing what's in your project settings, it's hard to tell.

---

**UPDATE** The screenshot shows a different error than the description.

At this point, you need to start digging. Go to that directory. Make sure that file exists.

If the file doesn't exist, you need to look at the `A3WebCoreDataStaticLibrary` target and see why it's not building the framework where you expect it to be.

If the file does exist, then you need to check the build order. It may be building the framework after it tries to build your app.

Comment: I have attached fatal error log screenshot . /*/ is the physical path . you can see the full path in screen shot. Same project is running with Xcode 6.3 . What are changes I suppose to do for make it run in Xcode 7.

Comment: @AvijitDas I've included a couple of things for you to check, but there still isn't enough detail to say what the actual failure is.